# Apple reject because App crashed on iPad Air

Tags: ipad, air, crash

```
    "bundleID":???,"app_name":???,"bug_type":"109","name":???,"os_version":"iPhone OS 7.1.1     (11D201)","version":"1000 (1.0)"}
    Incident Identifier: ???
    CrashReporter Key:   ???
    Hardware Model:      xxx
    Process:             ??? [5936]
    Path:                ???
    Identifier:          ???
    Version:             1000 (1.0)
    Code Type:           ARM (Native)
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]

    Date/Time:           2014-05-13 08:44:16.722 -0700
    OS Version:          iOS 7.1.1 (11D201)
    Report Version:      104

    Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
    Exception Subtype: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000166cf0
    Triggered by Thread:  0

    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   CoreGraphics                    0x2de4a727 argb32_mark + 35
    1   libRIP.A.dylib                  0x2e1ad35f RIPLayerBltGlyph + 3099
    2   libRIP.A.dylib                  0x2e1ab059 render_glyph_list + 281
    3   libRIP.A.dylib                  0x2e1aaef9 render_glyphs + 289
    4   libRIP.A.dylib                  0x2e1aacd3 draw_glyph_bitmaps + 899
    5   libRIP.A.dylib                  0x2e19d8f9 ripc_DrawGlyphs + 1733
    6   CoreGraphics                    0x2df014a7 draw_glyphs + 839
    7   CoreGraphics                    0x2de4e7f7 CGContextShowGlyphsWithAdvances + 399
    8   CoreText                        0x2e49b67d CTFontDrawGlyphsWithAdvances + 1701
    9   UIFoundation                    0x35cbe45b __NSStringDrawingEngine + 6947
    10  UIFoundation                    0x35cbc85f -[NSString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) 
    ...
    ...

    Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x1e1e2e8c    r1: 0x00167fe0      r2: 0x3ac3e074      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000000    r5: 0xffffffff      r6: 0x00167fe0      r7: 0x00167f14
    r8: 0x00000014    r9: 0x00000002     r10: 0x00167fe0     r11: 0x1e1e2e70
    ip: 0x00000022    sp: 0x00166cc0      lr: 0x2e1ad361      pc: 0x2de4a726
  cpsr: 0x40000030
```

I already test to run in all version of simulator, no crash occur. But When submit to app store, apple said my app crash in IPad Air.

Please tell me how to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: You need to test on the actual device. You cannot rely on a simulator, especially not the AIR simulator. If you are running a Mac, you can test using the iOS Simulator, which is far more accurate than the AIR Simulator, but you should still test on the actual device.